# Submitting spring form on select change event passing parameter

Tags: spring, select, parameters, onchange

I an using Spring 3.x and attempting to submit a form when the value of a drop down changes - in such a way that the controller can properly determine which method to call:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myContainer" action="/credits/processAssignment.ntwx"
        method="post" name="assignmentsForm">

<form:select path="currentCreditId" width="400" onchange="submit()">
<c:forEach items="${creditIds}" var="creditId">
<form:option value="${creditId}" >
</c:forEach>                                    
</form:option>
</form:select>
...other controls and submit buttons
</form:form>
```

When the value of the select/drop-down changes, I would like to have it call this method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/credits/processAssignment.ntwx", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
params="creditIdChanged" )
public ModelAndView creditIdChanged( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response, @ModelAttribute("myContainer") MyContainer myContainer, ModelMap model)
```

I think the key to this is figuring out how to pass the param 'creditIdChanged' from the dropdown. I have a few submit buttons on the page that pass the param by their name attribute:

```
<input type="submit" name="addRow" value="Add Row" class="button" />
```

This will pass the param 'addRow', so it's easy to map this submit to a controller method. Using the name='creditIdChanged' or id='creditIdChanged' of the form:select does not pass creditIdChanged as the parameter.

Any Suggestions?